# How to index a query the right way

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, indexing

I am trying to make my DB more optimized and are in the beginning of indexing it but not sure how to do it right.

I have this query:

```
$year = date("Y");
$thisYear = $year;
//$nextYear = $thisYear + 1; 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(points) as userpoints
                                          FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints
                                          WHERE date BETWEEN '$thisYear" . "-01-01' AND '$thisYear" . "-12-31' AND fk_player_id = $playerid");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); 
$userPoints = $row['userpoints'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT 
                       fk_player_id
                    FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints
                    WHERE date BETWEEN '$thisYear" . "-01-01' AND '$thisYear" . "-12-31'
                    GROUP BY fk_player_id
                    HAVING SUM(points) > $userPoints");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$userWrank = mysql_num_rows($sql)+1;
```

I am not sure how to index this? I have tried indexing the fk_player_id but it still looks through all the rows (287937).

I have indexed the date field which gives me this back in EXPLAIN:

**1
SIMPLE
nf_publicpoints
range
IDXdate
IDXdate
3
NULL
143969
Using where with pushed condition; Using temporary...**

I also have 2 calls to the same table... Could that be done in one?

How do I index this and/or could it be done smarter?

Comment: Could you post the result of Explain for this query? see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html
for more information

Comment: I have edited post with the explain and an extra question!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely spend some time reading up on indexing, there's a lot written about it, and it's important to understand what's going on.

Broadly speaking, and index imposes an ordering on the rows of a table.

For simplicity's sake, imagine a table is just a big CSV file. Whenever a row is inserted, it's inserted at the end. So the "natural" ordering of the table is just the order in which rows were inserted.

Imagine you've got that CSV file loaded up in a very rudimentary spreadsheet application. All this spreadsheet does is display the data, and numbers the rows in sequential order.

Now imagine that you need to find all the rows that has some value "M" in the third column. Given what you have available, you have only one option. You scan the table checking the value of the third column for each row. If you've got a lot of rows, this method (a "table scan") can take a long time!

Now imagine that in addition to this table, you've got an index. This particular index is the index of values in the third column. The index lists all of the values from the third column, in some meaningful order (say, alphabetically) and for each of them, provides a list of row numbers where that value appears.

Now you have a good strategy for finding all the rows where the value of the third column is M! For instance, you can perform a binary search! Whereas the table scan requires you to look N rows (where N is the number of rows), the binary search only requires that you look at log-n index entries, in the very worst case. Wow, that's sure a lot easier!

Of course, if you have this index, and you're adding rows to the table (at the end, since that's how our conceptual table works), you need need to update the index each and every time. So you do a little more work while you're writing new rows, but you save a ton of time when you're searching for something.

So, in general, indexing creates a tradeoff between read efficiency and write efficiency. With no indexes, inserts can be very fast -- the database engine just adds a row to the table. As you add indexes, the engine must update each index while performing the insert.

On the other hand, reads become a lot faster.

Hopefully that covers your first two questions (as others have answered -- you need to find the right balance).

Your third scenario is a little more complicated. If you're using LIKE, indexing engines will typically help with your read speed up to the first "%". In other words, if you're SELECTing WHERE column LIKE 'foo%bar%', the database will use the index to find all the rows where column starts with "foo", and then need to scan that intermediate rowset to find the subset that contains "bar". SELECT ... WHERE column LIKE '%bar%' can't use the index. I hope you can see why.

Finally, you need to start thinking about indexes on more than one column. The concept is the same, and behaves similarly to the LIKE stuff -- essentialy, if you have an index on (a,b,c), the engine will continue using the index from left to right as best it can. So a search on column a might use the (a,b,c) index, as would one on (a,b). However, the engine would need to do a full table scan if you were searching WHERE b=5 AND c=1)

Hopefully this helps shed a little light, but I must reiterate that you're best off spending a few hours digging around for good articles that explain these things in depth. It's also a good idea to read your particular database server's documentation. The way indices are implemented and used by query planners can vary pretty widely.

More information and example visit here : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/category/sql-index/

Comment: May this link help to you:http://www.slideshare.net/matsunobu/more-mastering-the-art-of-indexing

Answer (score 0):

Try create index on date column, indexing fk_payer_id will not help with this query. If does not work - paste explain...

For more information about indexes in Mysql look here: http://hackmysql.com/case1

Answer (score 0):

Why not index the date column, seeing how that's the main criterion that will be evaluated in the lookup?

Comment: Edited the post above with an explain and index on date.